# Scrolling up to a certain point

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made it so that the nav bar on my website does not move when scrolling occurs. I would like for the page below it, to scroll up to a certain point, then stop, and allow scrolling through the rest of the page. I.E. I have the nav bar and under it an image. Below that is a heading. I want the image to scroll up behind the nav bar, but for this behavior to stop when it reaches the navbar and for the heading to be beneath the nav bar. How can I achieve this? I am new to JS, CSS, and HTML so I don't know where to begin. My searches on the web have not provided the necessary results, probably because I am no good at wording my questions. Thanks in advance for any help! P.S. not trying to have someone "do it for me", but "show me how to do it". This is not something I came across in my book that I have been following, "Learn Web Design".

Andy

Comment: I suggest you take a look at in the information at W3Schools.com [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp).

Comment: @YCode That addresses how to build a navbar, but not the part of getting the heading to get fixed underneath the navbar and stay there when you scroll down far enough.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

If I'm understanding your goal properly, what you're looking for is [position: sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Check it out:

```css
nav, div, h1 {
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
}

nav {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  background: blue;
}

h1 {
  background: green;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav>navbar</nav>

<div>image</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ratione quasi reiciendis assumenda! Accusamus, harum molestiae! Cumque laboriosam quasi pariatur minima, quas eaque? Illo et sunt qui voluptate, neque dolores?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ratione quasi reiciendis assumenda! Accusamus, harum molestiae! Cumque laboriosam quasi pariatur minima, quas eaque? Illo et sunt qui voluptate, neque dolores?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ratione quasi reiciendis assumenda! Accusamus, harum molestiae! Cumque laboriosam quasi pariatur minima, quas eaque? Illo et sunt qui voluptate, neque dolores?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ratione quasi reiciendis assumenda! Accusamus, harum molestiae! Cumque laboriosam quasi pariatur minima, quas eaque? Illo et sunt qui voluptate, neque dolores?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ratione quasi reiciendis assumenda! Accusamus, harum molestiae! Cumque laboriosam quasi pariatur minima, quas eaque? Illo et sunt qui voluptate, neque dolores?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ratione quasi reiciendis assumenda! Accusamus, harum molestiae! Cumque laboriosam quasi pariatur minima, quas eaque? Illo et sunt qui voluptate, neque dolores?</div>

<h1>heading</h1>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ratione quasi reiciendis assumenda! Accusamus, harum molestiae! Cumque laboriosam quasi pariatur minima, quas eaque? Illo et sunt qui voluptate, neque dolores?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ratione quasi reiciendis assumenda! Accusamus, harum molestiae! Cumque laboriosam quasi pariatur minima, quas eaque? Illo et sunt qui voluptate, neque dolores?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ratione quasi reiciendis assumenda! Accusamus, harum molestiae! Cumque laboriosam quasi pariatur minima, quas eaque? Illo et sunt qui voluptate, neque dolores?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ratione quasi reiciendis assumenda! Accusamus, harum molestiae! Cumque laboriosam quasi pariatur minima, quas eaque? Illo et sunt qui voluptate, neque dolores?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ratione quasi reiciendis assumenda! Accusamus, harum molestiae! Cumque laboriosam quasi pariatur minima, quas eaque? Illo et sunt qui voluptate, neque dolores?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ratione quasi reiciendis assumenda! Accusamus, harum molestiae! Cumque laboriosam quasi pariatur minima, quas eaque? Illo et sunt qui voluptate, neque dolores?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ratione quasi reiciendis assumenda! Accusamus, harum molestiae! Cumque laboriosam quasi pariatur minima, quas eaque? Illo et sunt qui voluptate, neque dolores?</div>
```

`position: sticky` basically says "Act like a `relative`ly positioned element until you scroll all the way down to it. Then act like an element with `fixed` position." But we have to make sure we have a `top: 50px`, because we already have the `nav` as `fixed`, so if we didn't have `top: 50px` it'd default to `top: 0px`, which would be taking up the same space as the `nav`, and the `nav` would be on top of it. So `top: 50px` pushes it underneath the `nav`.

---

FWIW, I've been doing front end professionally for six years, and it's something that I didn't know how to do initially and also struggled to figure out the right thing to search. It's an awkward thing to phrase. But as you seem to understand, learning how to google and figure this sort of stuff out comes with experience.

My process went like this.

- First I tried to phrase the "two navbars but one becomes a navbar once you scroll to it" thing in google. I was hoping to find Stack Overflow posts or blog posts showing how to do it. It didn't work.
- From there you could try a more general search of something like "navbar css". Obviously that's not specific to your question, but sometimes you'll be able to navigate through a few pages of search results and be lucky enough to stumble upon what you're looking for.
- I didn't try that though. From my experience, I had an idea that there was some value for `position` that might be what'd do the trick, so I knew to look there, and sure enough, it was `position: sticky`. I was already familiar with the first four values. That's kinda par for the course for a web developer. I had an idea that there was a fifth (and maybe sixth or seventh) new value that I wasn't immediately familiar with, so I figured I'd look it up.

I'm not sure how helpful that is to you though. Anyway, keep at it!